# I do not see the problem with this data class

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, jsonparser

Got this error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1" when trying to parse this to json

```
data class RegisterRequest(val email: String, val username: String, val password: String)

@POST("/api/user/create")
suspend fun register(@Body request: RegisterRequest) : BasicApiResponse<Unit>


@Provides
@Singleton
fun AuthApi(): AuthApi{
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(AuthApi.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(AuthApi::class.java)
}
```

Comment: The error message says it. You are not dealing with a JSON string.

Comment: Can you share your code, you are using to serialize an object of the given class to json?

Comment: that is all code i have but what i get it as is that the @Body should parse what i send in if im correct no?